# Сетчатый прайс в sql

Tags: php, mysql

Решил вернуть тему, дабы поползав в парсинге эксель через php понял, что не вариант.
Вопрос такой, как создать таблицу mysql для получения стоимости в зависимости от ширины/высоты и категории, с учетом того, что есть 4 вида изделия и в каждом по 5 таких таблиц?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Возможно ли делать выборку стоимости изделия из SQL* Да. *может есть другой способ брать цену?* Скорее всего есть.

Comment: @spoon100500 так вы покажите свою бд, зависимости там и все необходимое. или как мы вам разъясним и тем более покажем примеры?

Comment: *как реализовать такую таблицу* `CREATE TABLE MyData (id, productID, categoryID, width, height, price)`. Есссно с правильными типами данных, индексами (включая первичный) и внешними ключами.

Comment: @spoon100500 Да, конечно можно и прямо из ексель брать. Практически для любого языка программирования есть готовые библиотеки для работы с ексель файлами, в том числе для перечисленных в тегах php и js (достаточно вбить в гугле название языка и слово excel)